# Shifting Adjusted data inside for loop

Tags: excel, vba

so ive written the code I need and it works how its intended. The only problem I am having is removing blank rows and shifting the remaining data up before the next iteration in my for loop. If any one has a suggestion im all ears. My reasoning behind this is that once the duplicates are removed blank rows are left in their place and as a result the currentregion value changes when calculating numrow.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub dup()
Dim i As Integer
Dim updater As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Range
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim startcell As Range
Dim numrow As Long
Dim rcell As String
Dim LastCell As Range
Set updater = Worksheets("DbVisualizer Personal")

'-----------------------------------------------------
numrow = updater.Range("A4").CurrentRegion.rows.Count
For i = 4 To numrow
    rcell = updater.Cells(i, 30)
    Set startcell = updater.Cells(i, 1)
    'Set LastRow = startcell.Offset(1, 0)
    Set LastCell = updater.Cells(i + 10, 35)
    If rcell = "Y" Then
        Else
         updater.Range(startcell.Address, LastCell.Address).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(7, 17), Header:=xlNo
            End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Find blanks using `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)` and then delete.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest sorting your data with the sort function, because that will automatically move blanks to the bottom and all your data to the top.